# Add "filter" buttons to Scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, swift3

I'm new to swift and i'm learning the language with re-creating an Instagram kind of app. I have a problem with the filters. When i run it on the simulator everything works fine except of the scrollview. it should show all the filters like it is on the Instagram app. but it only shows 1 filter (the last one of CIFilternames) how can i get the other filters as a button next to the one which is there?

[in the Scrollview should be more filters than one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMdOE.jpg)

```
 var CIFilterNames = [
    "CIPhotoEffectChrome",
    "CIPhotoEffectFade",
    "CIPhotoEffectInstant",
    "CIPhotoEffectNoir",
    "CIPhotoEffectProcess",
    "CIPhotoEffectTonal",
    "CIPhotoEffectTransfer",
    "CISepiaTone",
    "CIPhotoEffectInstant",
        ]




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    imageview.image = receivedImage

    var xCoord: CGFloat = 5
    let yCoord: CGFloat = 10
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 70
    let gapBetweenButtons: CGFloat = 5

    var itemCount = 0

    for i in 0..<CIFilterNames.count {
        itemCount = i

        // Button properties
        let filterButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        filterButton.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 10, width: 70, height: 70)
        filterButton.tag = itemCount
        filterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(secendTestViewController.filterButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        filterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        filterButton.clipsToBounds = true




        // Create filters for each button
        let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
        let coreImage = CIImage(image: receivedImage)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "\(CIFilterNames[i])" )
        filter!.setDefaults()
        filter!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let filteredImageData = filter!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
        let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent)
        let imageForButton = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!);

        filterButton.setBackgroundImage(imageForButton, for: .normal)

        // Add Buttons in the Scroll View
        xCoord += buttonWidth + gapBetweenButtons

        filterScrollView.addSubview(filterButton)
    } // END FOR LOOP

    // Resize Scroll View
   filterScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(buttonWidth * CGFloat(itemCount + 2), yCoord)


    }



func filterButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let button = sender as UIButton

    imageToFilter.image = button.backgroundImage(for: UIControlState.normal)
}
```

Comment: i think you need to change  filterButton.frame

Comment: set  CGRect(x: xCoord, y: 10, width: 70, height: 70)

Comment: Why don't you use a `UICollectionView` instead? It is designed for the purpose you are trying to achieve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is filterButton frame.
try this

```
filterButton.frame = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: 10, width: 70, height: 70)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! you saved my day! i've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days now! I understand my mistake now LOL thanks!

Comment: i feel glad to help you